# Multiple Cell Selection on TableView

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, tableview

I'm having an issue where when I'm selecting the cell for e.g at index 3 , it selecting cells below also at random indexes. Check and Uncheck cell is working but for some reasons when selecting a cell it is selecting other cells as well. **My array is returning 120 rows in total.** I have selected multiple touch. Thank you for the help.

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int{

    return arrayVerbCount.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell{

    let cell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! MesTalentsChoixCell

    cell.verb!.text = arrayVerbCount[indexPath.row].verb

    if cell.isSelected
    {
        cell.isSelected = false
        if cell.accessoryType == UITableViewCellAccessoryType.none
        {
            cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.checkmark
        }
        else
        {
            cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.none
        }
    }

    return cell
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath){

    let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)

    if cell!.isSelected
    {
        cell!.isSelected = false
        if cell!.accessoryType == UITableViewCellAccessoryType.none
        {
            cell!.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.checkmark
        }
        else
        {
            cell!.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.none
        }
    }
}
```

My custom cell class:

```
class MesTalentsChoixCell: UITableViewCell {

@IBOutlet weak var verb: UILabel!

override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    // Initialization code
}

override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

    // Configure the view for the selected state
}

}
```

Comment: Since the tableViewCell is reused in func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) it would retain the same state for other cells aswell. So to overcome this problem you can make use of Set. Whenever the object is selected you can store them in set or add a bool variable 'isSelected' in your verb class, whenever cell is selected make it true. Show the check mark only when the verb.isSelected = true.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should do like this way, this is very much easy solution if there is only one section.

Initialize `selectedItems` array like this,

```
var selectedItems: [Int] = []
```

Find `UITableViewDataSource` method below

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CustomCell") as! CustomCell
    cell.tmpValue.text = data[indexPath.row]

    if selectedItems.contains(indexPath.row) {
        cell.accessoryType = .checkmark
    } else {
        cell.accessoryType = .none
    }

    return cell
}
```

Find `UITableViewDelegate` Method below.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)

    if selectedItems.contains(indexPath.row) {
        let index = selectedItems.index(of: indexPath.row)
        selectedItems.remove(at: index!)
    } else {
        selectedItems.append(indexPath.row)
    }

    tableView.reloadRows(at: [indexPath], with: .none)
}
```

Code will be changed depending on your requirement and custom cell. Hope you can do it your way. Thank you.

**UPDATE**

You can even use `Set` also like this way,

```
var setSelectedItems: Set<Int> = []
```

`UITableViewDataSource` method,

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CustomCell") as! CustomCell
    cell.tmpValue.text = data[indexPath.row]

    if setSelectedItems.contains(indexPath.row) {
        cell.accessoryType = .checkmark
    } else {
        cell.accessoryType = .none
    }

    return cell
}
```

`UITableViewDelegate` method,

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)

    if setSelectedItems.contains(indexPath.row) {
        setSelectedItems.remove(indexPath.row)
    } else {
        setSelectedItems.insert(indexPath.row)
    }
    tableView.reloadRows(at: [indexPath], with: .none)
}
```

Comment: Make use of SET instead of an array.

Comment: @PPL Thank you for the answer

Answer (score 1):

Make bool array for stability while scrolling i.e.

```
var arrStatusBool = [Bool]()
```

Now set value at indexPath.row in **didSelectRowAt**

```
public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) 
{
    if self.arrStatusBool[indexPath.row]
    {
        self.arrStatusBool[indexPath.row] = false
    } 
    else 
    {
        self.arrStatusBool[indexPath.row] = true
    }
}
```

And also put this in **cellForRowAt** to avoid scrolling issue.

```
if self.arrStatusBool[indexPath.row]
{
     tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)?.accessoryType = .checkmark
} 
else 
{
    tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)?.accessoryType = .none
}
```

hope this help!

Answer (score 0):

For multiple selection you should track selected cells in a `Dictionary` for convenience faster access to selected and unselected indexPaths allowing you use multiple sections because the key value of our Dictionary is a string formed by (IndexPath.section)+(IndexPath.row) which is always unique combination

```
var selectedIndexPaths : [String:Bool] = [:]

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    let currentIndexPathStr = "\(indexPath.section)\(indexPath.row)"
    if(self.selectedIndexPaths[currentIndexPathStr] == nil || !self.selectedIndexPaths[currentIndexPathStr]!) {
        self.selectedIndexPaths[currentIndexPathStr] = true
    }else{
        self.selectedIndexPaths[currentIndexPathStr] = false
    }
    self.tableView.reloadRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)
}


public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "npCell", for: indexPath) as! NewPlaylistTableViewCell

        cell.mTitle.text = musics[indexPath.row]["title"] as! String?
        cell.mArtist.text = musics[indexPath.row]["artist"] as! String?

        cell.accessoryType = .checkmark
        let currentIndexPathStr = "\(indexPath.section)\(indexPath.row)"
        if(self.selectedIndexPaths[currentIndexPathStr] == nil || !self.selectedIndexPaths[currentIndexPathStr]!)  {
           cell.accessoryType = .none
        }

        return cell
    }
```

**Results**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Just a minor change

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell{

    let cell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! MesTalentsChoixCell

    cell.verb!.text = arrayVerbCount[indexPath.row].verb

    if cell.isSelected
    {
       cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.checkmark
    }
    else
    {
       cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.none
    }

    return cell
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath){

    let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)

    //toggle the state
    cell!.isSelected = !cell!.isSelected

    if cell!.isSelected
    {
        cell!.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.checkmark 
    }
    else
    {
        cell!.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.none
    }
}
```

> Note: you should also create method for common code :-)